# Spring Validator Junit Error

Tags: spring, junit, validation

I am writing junit test for validators. Below code works:

```
// initialize errors
errors = createNiceMock(BindingResult.class);
errors.rejectValue("orgId", "mismatch.LaunchQueryForm.orgId");

// activate the mock
replay(errors);

// go ahead and run validate now
launchQueryValidator.validate(launchQueryForm, errors);

// verify the errors
verify(errors);
```

However below doesn't work in junit - the difference here is that i am sending an additional parameter to display in the error message, Any idea how to write junit for this?

```
errors.rejectValue("typeInput", "mismatch.LaunchQueryForm.typeInput",
                           new Object[]
                { launchQueryForm.getTypeInput() }, null);
```

Error i get in this case is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    BindingResult.rejectValue("typeInput", "mismatch.LaunchQueryForm.typeInput", ["X"], null): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Best,
Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem indicates that it's not a good idea to use mock in this case.

Use real `BindingResult` implementation and check its state instead:

```
BindingResult errors = 
    new BeanPropertyBindingResult(launchQueryForm, "LaunchQueryForm");

launchQueryValidator.validate(launchQueryForm, errors);

assertEquals("mismatch.LaunchQueryForm.orgId", 
    errors.getFieldError("orgId").getCode());
```

Comment: Got this workign in the past like this, I was curious about the other way as my junit setup is filled with easymock. Thanks for the note anyways.